# Running a batch file present in Apache server using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, apache

We are trying to run a bat file present in apache server using the java script.
    We are getting following error “Automation server cannot create the object”
    Please find the below code and let us know how to resolve the issue

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script>    
    function testing() {
        alert("Execution will start");
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        alert("after webShell");
        //var commandtoRun = "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Group\\Apache2\\htdocs\\application\\gui\\templates\\execute\\test.bat";

        WshShell.Run ("\"C:\\Program Files\\Apache Group\\Apache2\\htdocs\\application\\gui\\templates\\execute\\test.bat\"");

        alert("after webShell");

    }

    </script>

</head>


    enter code here
    <body> 

    <form>

    <p id="demo">Running scripts </p>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript: testing ();" value="Run Scripts" />
    <button onclick="javascript: testing ();">Run bat File</button>

    </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this as ActiveX and not as CGI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript executes at client side. the location u have provided it will refer to the client machine. either you put your file at client side at given location or write server  side code. as follows. i hope you are using jsp.

e.g.

```
    <% String script="Write your script"%>
    <script> 
function testing(var script) {        
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");              
        WshShell.Run (script);       
    }

var script1=<%=script%>
testing(script1);

    </script>
```